# I got locked out of my heroku account (lost 2FA code)

Tags: heroku

I wiped my older phone with the 2FA app and now I can't log in. Heroku support email are not answering me for over 2 weeks... Anyone have a solution or maybe another heroku support email? (Couldn't find more than 1)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here...

They created a ticket for me, but to be able to comment or see the status you need to log in to your account :D

Not helping a lot. My problem is still not solved a week after I reported it....

I used this email: account-lockout@heroku.com